# Duda de concepto sobre función queda devuelve referencia lvalue

Tags: c++11

Se me ha planteado la siguiente duda. Si tengo una función que devuelve una referencia lvalue. Entiendo que al ser lvalue, puede estar en la parte izquierda de una igualdad. Pero lo que no entiendo, es porque a está referencia devuelta por la función, se le pueden asignar valores rvalues. Pensé que solo podía asignarse lvalue.

Pongo un ejemplo rapido de lo que comento:

```
 class Block
 {
     private:
        int _n_block;
     public:
        Block(int x):_n_block(n)
        {
        }   
}
class MemoryBlock
{
    private:
       int x;
       Block& _b;

    public:
           Block& getBlock() const
           {
                 return _b;
           }
           MemoryBlock(int x,Block r):_b(r)
           {
                this->x=x;

           }
}

int main(){
    MemoryBlock m(0,b); // creo un objeto MemoryBlock m.
    m.getBlock()=Block(7)
    //Sobre m llamo al metodo getBlock() que devuelve Block&
}
```

No entiendo porque puedo asignarle a Block& un objeto temporal rvalue.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Me temo que no entiendo bien tu pregunta; lo que muestras se puede hacer desde que C++ tiene referencias. `'a'` es una `const char &`.

Comment: Vale, voy reeditar la pregunta con otro codigo, mal ejemplo. De todas, formas porque no da problemas al igualar char&=const char&. porque con char& podría modificar algo que en principio es intocable.

Comment: Nope. `char & = const char &` crea **una copia**; podrás modificar la copia, pero **nunca** el original.

Comment: Crea una "copia" llamando al operador asignación? pensé que se igualaban referencias no objetos.

Comment: Gracia, pensé que era igualar referencias y no me cuadraba, por cuestión de lvalue y rvalue. Y voy mas lejos, si tengo un objeto rvalue a la derecha, Entiendo que se llamará a mi operador de asignación de movimiento, si lo tengo definido. Muchas gracias, otra vez más.

Comment: Podrías explicarme lo de resferenciar y desreferenciar, porque no lo veo con un ejemplo, porfavor. Porque yo, pensaba que si tengo por ejemplo una int& r2=3. con r2(hago la desreferencia) es decir accedo al objeto y con &r2 la dirección del objeto. Independientemente de izquierda o derecha del =. Perdona por se pesado.

Comment: A ver, una cosa rápida: con punteros, tienes que referenciar tu explícito: `int *x; *x = 5`; con referencias, **no hace falta**: `int &a = b; a = 5;`. Eso hace que se comporte de forma distinta si está a la izquierda o a la derecha. A la izquierda, es como un `*x` automático. A la derecha, es como un `&x` automático. Y recuerda que solo puedes asignarles un valor al declararlas. Posteriores uso equivalen a llamar al `operator=`. Me falta teoría para explicartelo con mas detalle, lo siento :-(

Comment: gracias estupendo, muy claro todo. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este método:

```
Block& getBlock() const
{
  return _b;
}
```

Lo que hace es exponer el objeto `_b` al exterior de la clase. Un ejemplo un poco más gráfico sería el siguiente:

```
Block* getBlock() const
{
  return &_b;
}
```

Aquí no habría ninguna duda de que cualquiera podría modificar el objeto `_b`  desde fuera de la clase simplemente llamando a `getBlock`... pues con la referencia pasa exactamente lo mismo.

Lo que sucede en esta línea:

```
m.getBlock()=Block(7)
```

Es lo siguiente:

- Se crea un *Rvalue* de tipo `Block` con `_n_block=7`
- El método `getBlock` expone una referencia a `_b`. Es decir, es como si `_b` fuese público.
- Se llama al operador de asignación, `_b = Block(7)`. Como no has implementado un operador de forma explícita se invoca al operador *move* (`Block& operator=(Block&&)`)
- Se destruye el objeto *Rvalue* creado en el primer paso.

El comportamiento que describes es el esperado. El problema es que estás confundiendo conceptos. Tu has asumido que `getBlock` debe ser un *Rvalue*  porque es una función... y las funciones son inmutables... pero lo importante en este caso no es `getBlock` sino lo que devuelve dicha función. Si `getBlock` devolviese una referencia constante o un objeto por valor:

```
Block const& getBlock()
Block getBlock()
```

Entonces sí que te encontrarías con errores en tiempo de compilación... pero no en este caso.

Un ejemplo muy similar lo puedes encontrar en el uso de la función `tie`, que sirve para explotar un `pair` o un `tuple`:

```
std::pair<int,bool> pareja = std::make_pair(123,true);
int numero;
bool booleano;
std::tie(numero,booleano) = pareja;
std::cout << numero << ' ' << booleano;
```

De primeras el código parece contraintuitivo ya que no se le puede asignar nada a una función... ¿o sí? Si revisas la [documentación](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) de la función verás que devuelve un `tuple` con referencias. Dicho en cristiano y personalizándolo para el ejemplo que te he puesto la especialización de `tie` (que efectivamente es una plantilla) sería la siguiente:

```
std::tuple<int&,bool&> tie(int& a, bool& b)
{
  return {a,b};
}
```

Es decir, crea una tupla de referencias. Si modificas la tupla estarás modificando una de las variables con las que has llamado a `tie`... la llamada a `tie` no es un *Rvalue* sino un *Lvalue*.